# Debugging regular expressions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, regex

In Python, there is a special [`re.DEBUG` flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DEBUG) that would display the regular expression parse tree:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> data = "myid_01234"
>>> re.match(r"^myid_(\d+)$", data, re.DEBUG)
at at_beginning
literal 109
literal 121
literal 105
literal 100
literal 95
subpattern 1
  max_repeat 1 4294967295
    in
      category category_digit
at at_end
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x104ffe7b0>
```

Is it possible to get a similar debug information with a parse tree in JavaScript?

```
> var re = /^myid_(\d+)$/;
> var data = "myid_01234"
> data.match(re)
["myid_01234", "01234"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript does not offer this.

But you can use an online service or software to debug it.
Example: https://regex101.com/r/vY0iK9/1

Comment: https://www.debuggex.com/ is also a nice tool to manually advance a match attempt

Comment: I used debuggex for a long time, the graphing feature is pretty neat. These site have both pretty much the same functionality, so I guess it's a matter of opinion.